# flutter google sign in

Tags: flutter, authentication, oauth, google-signin

I am trying to use google sign in and I have verified my app

[!{this image from inside my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7i8N.jpg)

[this image from OAuth consent screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJizu.png)

this sample of my code to sign in and the lib is  google_sign_in: ^5.2.1

```
   GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
    GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication =
        await googleSignInAccount.authentication;
```

Answer (score 0):

This warning means that the app isn't verified but you are sharing data to it. Click on advanced and select continue to complete the flow. This will automatically be removed after verification.

Comment: but the is already verified check this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJizu.png

Comment: Have you added sensitive scopes in OAuthConsent screen https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/consent

Comment: no only  non-sensitive scopes
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJizu.png

Comment: You are accessing user details which are sensitive ones. Maybe you need to add them